# I want to show a toast error msg if the edittext section is blank when the button is pressed (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android

I made a simple calculator app in android studio but the app crashes when no value is entered in the edittext section.
I want to show a toast msg when no value is entered in the edittext section.
Please check this issue and guide me how to fix this and add toast.
here n1 and n2 is the id of edittext.

MainActivity (code):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    n1 = findViewById(R.id.n1);
    n2 = findViewById(R.id.n2);
    add = findViewById(R.id.add);
    sub = findViewById(R.id.sub);
    multi = findViewById(R.id.multi);
    div = findViewById(R.id.div);
    tv = findViewById(R.id.tv);

    // addition part

    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int p,q,r;
            p = Integer.parseInt(n1.getText().toString());
            q = Integer.parseInt(n2.getText().toString());
            r = p+q;
            tv.setText("Result is " + r);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Successfully Calculated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
    //subtraction part

    sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int p,q,r;
            p = Integer.parseInt(n1.getText().toString());
            q = Integer.parseInt(n2.getText().toString());
            r = p-q;
            tv.setText("Result is " + r);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Successfully Calculated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

    // multiplication part

    multi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int p,q,r;
            p = Integer.parseInt(n1.getText().toString());
            q = Integer.parseInt(n2.getText().toString());
            r = p*q;
            tv.setText("Result is " + r);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Successfully Calculated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

    //divison part

    div.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int p,q,r;
            p = Integer.parseInt(n1.getText().toString());
            q = Integer.parseInt(n2.getText().toString());
            r = p/q;
            tv.setText("Result is " + r);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Successfully Calculated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the same in all the other OnClickListner

```
add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int p,q,r;
                if(!n1.getText().toString().equals("") && !n2.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    p = Integer.parseInt(n1.getText().toString());
                    q = Integer.parseInt(n2.getText().toString());
                    r = (p + q);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Successfully Calculated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    tv.setText("Result is " + r);
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: C:\VS Code\Projects\SimpleCalculator\app\src\main\java\com\anish\simplecalculator\MainActivity.java:42: error: int cannot be dereferenced
                if(p.equals("") || q.equals("")){
                    ^                                                           showing error

Comment: Sorry i forgot it accepts only integer... use null instead of equals....i have updated my answer see if it works...?

Comment: ok lemme check it wait

Comment: same error   error: int cannot be dereferenced
                if(p.getText().isEmpty() || q.getText().isEmpty()){
                    ^

Comment: what about null did you try that i have given two solutions? @AnishDas

Comment: yeah tried both. You can check my file on github https://github.com/Anish-Das-GH/Simple_Calculator

Comment: I run your code and found the error solved it And updated my answer... Try This one and apply the same to other three And please accept my answer if it works !! :) @AnishDas

Answer (score 0):

You could do a preliminary check to see if any text was entered like

```
if(n1.getText()) ....
```

Ideally you'd want to surround the ParseInt() with a try{}..catch{} block and handle any errors there to stop the app from crashing.

Answer (score 0):

```
  int n1Value = n1.getText().toString();
  int n2Value = n2.getText().toString();
  p = n1Value !=null&&!n1Value.isEmpty()? Integer.parseInt(n1Value):0 
  p = n2Value !=null&&!n2Value.isEmpty()? Integer.parseInt(n2Value):0
```

Add this in your click listeners. the crash is happening because you don't have any null check.